# How do I approach a previous employer about a job opening?

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development, promotion

I worked for a construction company on a Federal project as the office admin working at the construction site. Upon completion of the project my employment was terminated as there were no other projects in my geographical area and my position with the company is/was considered to low to warrant moving me to another construction project.  The company has now been awarded another project near me and I am interested in working for them again, but in a different role on the project team that I know I can do. I was successful in my admin job, and my project team loved me, but I frequently butted heads with the admin supervisor back at headquarters, and I don't imagine she would readily recommend me coming back under any circumstances and may even consider blocking my attempt at reemployment. I've contacted the project manager that I worked with previously and I've asked him if he thinks I qualify for this new role and asked for his assistance in moving forward.  Is there anything else I should do pending his reply?  How should I handle potential interference from former admin supervisor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you work out "I frequently butted heads with the admin supervisor" = "successful in my admin job"?... you couldn't get on with your superior doesn't usually equate with success.

Comment: _I don't imagine she would readily recommend me coming back under **any** circumstances_ doesn't sound too good. I think you need to resolve the _butted heads_ with the admin supervisor, otherwise, you'll have trouble even you get the job.

Comment: There were two levels of supervision, one from the headquarters three states away and the other on site with the project team.  Interactions on the project team were great and positive but the admin supervisor at HQ is a very strong type A/OCD person who does not broker with any other course of action except her own.  Very inflexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in your application.

if your “butting heads” were screaming matches with claws drawn then you may not get far...

If, however, you were pointing out things that needed to be considered and your boss had to refuse them due to other considerations and you remained professional then they may want you back as you help cover the issues that need considering. Valid issues that are known about are one thing, issues not covered at all are another....

Go for it and good luck.

Comment: I'm hoping my former PM comes thru and makes a recommendation on my behalf to the hiring authorities.  His opinion carries weight and I do trust his opinion.  Either way I plan on applying.  Will let you know how it goes.